# HIDE/SHOW COLUMN VALUE BASED ON PARAMETER SELECTION IN SSRS REPORT

Tags: ssrs-2008

In my SSRS report I have one tablix with 10 columns. One column is named "field_type" and has three values: banking, healthcare, and insurance.

I'm using one parameter whose value contains 0 or 1. My requirement is if the parameter value is 1 then we have to display the field_type value as insurance in the report. If the parameter value is 0 then field_type value should be banking and healthcare in the report.

How can I write an expression to solve this? Could anyone suggest one to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add some logic so that you will filter your data one way when the parameter is set to 1 and another way when the parameter is 0.

You can either filter your data in the query or in the dataset.

The report will usually run faster if you filter in the query rather that the dataset but it's not always possible.

### SQL:

WHERE   (
    (field_type IN ('insurance') AND @PARAMETER = 1)
    OR
    (field_type IN ('banking', 'healthcare') AND @PARAMETER = 0)
    )

### SSRS Dataset:

**Expression:**

```
=IIF( 
    (Fields!field_type.Value = "insurance" AND Parameters!PARAMETER.Value = 1)
    OR (
        (
        Fields!field_type.Value = "banking" 
        OR
        Fields!field_type.Value = "healthcare" 
        )
        AND Parameters!PARAMETER.Value = 0)
    , 1, 0)
```

**Type**

Integer

**Value**

1

[image]